# Why scrapy spider returns different response than scrapy shell for the same request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping Bloomberg by requesting its internal API (XHR request) when I hit the desired endpoint within the scrapy shell environment with all the necessary request headers it works perfectly fine but when I hit the same endpoint with the same request headers within the spider it redirects me to the captcha page with the status code 307. here is my spider code following the scrapy shell screenshot:

```
import json
import scrapy

class IndexSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'index'
    start_urls = ['https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/comparison/geographic-indices?name=americas&type=region&securityType=COMMON_STOCK&locale=en']

    def parse(self, response):
        j_response = json.loads(response.text)
        print(j_response['fieldDataCollection'])
```

settings.py:

```
import scraper_helper as sh

BOT_NAME = 'bloomberg'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['bloomberg.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'bloomberg.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

DEFAULT_HEADERS = sh.get_dict('''
    accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
    cache-control: no-cache
    cookie: __sppvid=6e6bf4a2-73ec-4130-afc2-9bf738f772e9; _sp_krux=false; _sp_v1_uid=1:307:e3c04a31-b5ea-4638-8c6a-e097b1274305; _sp_v1_data=2:439307:1647871740:0:1:0:1:0:0:_:-1; _sp_v1_ss=1:H4sIAAAAAAAAAItWqo5RKimOUbLKK83J0YlRSkVil4AlqmtrlXRGlaEqiwUAXwon3zkBAAA%3D; _sp_v1_opt=1:; _sp_v1_csv=null; _sp_v1_lt=1:; consentUUID=f29fc90e-7858-4a04-881e-a9d844daf715; ccpaUUID=cf4c0e3b-8ef6-4891-a9ca-9dc2c7e661f5; dnsDisplayed=true; ccpaApplies=true; signedLspa=false; bbgconsentstring=req1fun1pad1; bdfpc=004.9625702412.1647871744510; _ga=GA1.2.378259085.1647871746; _gid=GA1.2.18075713.1647871746; _gcl_au=1.1.1555389317.1647871746; _dc_gtm_UA-11413116-1=1; pxcts=7804fd34-a920-11ec-89d0-615a6a494d7a; _pxvid=7804f22c-a920-11ec-89d0-615a6a494d7a; _px3=b7180b00a550bf4bd587ffbe00e33aa5f2ca79329dc4d294d2a12de428dbfbf1:zIW0/WP2EmZ1x9xI+NkMuqJMs8/+2VQrbqK1n257Cv/CENHGVb6x+eFx/3f0EwfZieEwOhMHWbX3lZLuxzWjfQ==:1000:RNPzkMJd5R47ycZKIkCsl2nu8MP0oMQIg/XtQBEDKOLSKty07fMPw2eQnHPm4sQ/1yw2pW2d/62dcKHjPoqrb7OSaRD4/vq+t3q27mV0s0roMJ7+Y30ZkJOJZC2esVaBXVSUQFNiCwLNIV4uHX2xKZSZJ4Jiqt4+dYh3nZZN0WkUtt8YOEtscG1kQKtLeZTlNb8YDH1Wh0qPW2MDGMXGgg==; _px2=eyJ1IjoiNzdiYmIyODAtYTkyMC0xMWVjLTg5ZjktMWQyMTcwYjEyYTQ0IiwidiI6Ijc4MDRmMjJjLWE5MjAtMTFlYy04OWQwLTYxNWE2YTQ5NGQ3YSIsInQiOjE2NDc4NzIwNDczNTksImgiOiI1NDkzMWFiODA3NjdkOWZlMjcyNjI2M2VkNzUwOTExNmRiMTZjMjY0N2E4ZTNjYzk5YTVkYWJmYjAyMDc4NmRhIn0=; _reg-csrf-token=FYpYX15K-_xNJhaP0YfHvaecZnu_qEU5_Oz4; _reg-csrf=s%3Ae0FDk6mZeXn5JQ3CcMF-NflM.2TwD26yIWghakuPTQmZCs2yiFlZ4U0xyglX%2FjURlHwQ; _user-status=anonymous; _user-data=%7B%22status%22%3A%22anonymous%22%7D; _last-refresh=2022-3-21%2014%3A9; __gads=ID=0aa56e0b7cc84e34-22234e56c4d10010:T=1647871748:S=ALNI_MbalsjdCdSZOoED3hR14CGfS0pgFA; _cc_id=6b16832337359998c28582ddac8f7ee5; _cc_cc=ACZ4XmNQMEsyNLMwNjI2Njc2tbS0tEg2sjC1MEpJSUy2SDNPTTVlAIIki3Y2EA0BIiuvTdFhPBTH8J%2BRkWHL2T1w9utV96Vh4ptXItjLb88Uh4mvXY8Qn7QJwV6DpPfHOoT4GyT28U1TWGDmPFs8B84%2Bd%2FQQM0x8977LAjD2YSQ175Yg1F%2F6aAlT8ui8Oow5fcsLXRh77%2BlHbDA2ACj1YfU%3D; _cc_aud=ABR4XmNgYGBIsmhnA1IQwMzAmlkEYrJmFoIorvK7QBIAR6QESA%3D%3D; panoramaId_expiry=1648476550509; panoramaId=23d7f54995f25eb4d11ece58777516d5393854a0c8e65e748390bcbe8dcdaaee; _uetsid=7baa89f0a92011ec88252746f19950be; _uetvid=7bab5090a92011ec85f6f55c9ea632af; _rdt_uuid=1647871752062.d191cccf-d47a-42d3-b99a-fe878ea498cd; _scid=16bd43e2-2b6e-436d-9b88-69bf66160c9f; _li_dcdm_c=.bloomberg.com; _lc2_fpi=b1166d620485--01fypcyya5b6azvhgceh7r7ctg; _fbp=fb.1.1647871755313.1570481249; trc_cookie_storage=taboola%2520global%253Auser-id%3D4fe773d5-42dc-4822-ac26-0dd8558a5fb7-tuct9320c93; _pxde=7f69c21d924808259dbacf8deb133ec45b458c8d3babb8887a884eb0057bb521:eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE2NDc4NzE3NjU0MjksImZfa2IiOjAsImlwY19pZCI6W119; _tb_sess_r=; _tb_t_ppg=https%3A//www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks
    pragma: no-cache
    referer: https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks/world-indexes/americas
    sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
    sec-fetch-dest: empty
    sec-fetch-mode: cors
    sec-fetch-site: same-origin
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.74 Safari/537.36
    ''')
```

scrapy shell screenshot:[scrapy shell screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8wKz.png)

Comment: maybe it doesn't get the same headers. Other problem can be: cookies usually are valid only short time and from time to time server sends new cookies - all for security. And it may need to work like real human - first get main page (to get fresh cookies) and next get other data. And it need to use Session to keep cookies between requests.

Comment: spider works for me even without headers and `response.text` gives the same result. Maybe you run shell and spider too many times in short time and this make problem.

Comment: well, for me without headers it does not even work in the scrapy shell, and as far as too many requests are concerned, it did not work in the spider for a single time, and it worked like a hundred times in the shell. However, refreshing cookies is a good idea.